# Is the high resolution for a 32 bit integer in boost::polygon out of date in Windows?

Tags: visual-studio, boost, boost-polygon

I recently tested [`boost::polygon`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/polygon/doc/index.htm) to perform complex Boolean unions of polygonal data with overlapping segments and many intersections to one point. I had to change the default `high_precision_type<int>::type` to `multiprecision::int128_t` because it defaults to `long double`. I wanted to capture 30 bits of an `int`. I suspect that this code was written back when `long double` was actually a `long double` by Visual Studio's MSVC compiler and not an euphemism for `double`.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue?

This is how the high precision integer operations can be overwritten by the user

```
namespace boost::polygon {
template<> struct high_precision_type<int64_t>
{
    using type = multiprecision::int128_t;
};

template<> struct high_precision_type<int>
{
    using type = multiprecision::int128_t;
};
}
```

Comment: You changed an IEEE float type to an integral type? Did you get a documented recommendation to do so? "I wanted to capture 30 bits of an int" - what does that mean in context?

Comment: Hey, @sehe, I am dealing with integers less than 2^31 in magnitude. Boost polygon relies on integer precision, but it uses long floats conditionally for extended int calculations, which became problematic when Windows dropped 80-bit support. No docs on  high_precision_type<int>::type. I assume you haven't worked with Boost. polygon based on your earlier IEEE-float-point question. F.Y.I., you can override locally high_precision_type<int>::type.

Comment: FWIW Windows hasn't dropped support for 80-bit floats, MSVC just chooses not to use them. If you really wanted to use 80-bit floats you still could, it would take more effort. But it looks like you don't need to do that.

Comment: @harold, thanks for your reply. I've found the boost multiprecision library to be incredibly user-friendly and powerful – kudos to J. Maddok for creating it!  Out of sheer academic curiosity, I would like to know how to enable 80-bit doubles in Visual Studio.

Comment: For example using Intel ICL compiler (not ICX) using the compilation flag [`/Qlong-double`](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/cpp-compiler/developer-guide-reference/2021-8/qlong-double.html) (it comes with some caveats), or if you must you could write functions for basic math operations in assembly and call them from C++ (beware of calling conventions, 80-bit float will have to be a struct basically).

Comment: Hehe; Perhaps you shouldn't [assume too soon](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/boost-polygon/topusers). I'm aware that Polygon makes few guarantees for non-integral coordinate types. Perhaps you can instead use multiprecision types - in which case you might not need floating point types. If you run into questions (which frequently happens due expression templates, e.g. https://github.com/boostorg/graph/pull/235 or https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A85371+boost+geometry+multiprecision) I'm happy to try to help out with the concrete problem

Comment: Hey, @sehe, the documentation clearly states, and I quote:  "The coordinate data type is a template parameter for all data types and algorithms provided by the library, and it is expected to be integral." Afterwards, he explains why floating point data is not supported. Please, read the documentation. Here's a link.
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/polygon/doc/index.htm

As I wrote in the question, I am using multi-precision types, integer types. I don't know if the multi-precision library was available when Lucanos introduced this library to boost.

Comment: Hi, @sehe, I think that I know the source of the confusion. Boost polygon is a library different from boost geometry.

Comment: @Catriel Yes, that is the documentation I was referring to, indeed. And no, the different libraries wasn't my confusion :) Sorry if my use of examples of using multiprecision with other libraries (like BGL and Geometry, indeed) gave you that impression. Regardless, if you have concrete questions, I'm here.

Comment: @sehe, thanks for the reply. I really was wondering if the default setting for the extended precision of the integer was out of date for Visual Studio's MSVC compiler. My hope was that someone else ran into the same problem. Frankly, I don't know what else to do besides changing the default. Cheers!